# Вопрос по Express JS - Возможно ли и как передать переменную от сервера на клиент (html)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, веб-сервер

И так есть сервер express и локальная html страница.
Всё что я хочу это вызвать alert на странице html после redirect или после render, но тогда нужно передать и изменить переменную true/false на клиент перед redirect, что бы использовать условия для проверки перед загрузкой страницы.
Сам процесс:
Есть Post запрос от клиента серверу. Передаются данные и записываются на сервер и в БД. Далее я хочу сообщить клиенту (то есть в html страницу) - что да запись успешна, нет запись не успешна или БД не отвечает (ну что то вроде этого). Вопрос как это можно реализовать. По факту существует одна страница. думаю это важно.

Сам проект с кодом выложен на GitHub: [ссылка на мой первый проект](https://github.com/Suvor4eg/VacuumWork.git)

Comment: запрос на сервер как делается? аяксом? в ответе вот и возвращайте данные и в аяксе применяйте

Comment: Нет его пока не освоил, я использовал body-parser и просто отлавливал форму. (<form action="/" method="post">)

Comment: Вставьте на сервере в html тег `<script>window.myVar = 123;</script>` и переменная `myVar` будет глобальной в JS. Ну и соответственно 123 замените на что-то своё.